# whenever I run my python code it should close running application

Tags: python

I am working on an project which is using opencv. this closes any opened application when an specific hand gesture is given.
So what I want is to close any application whenever I run my python code.
This code will be running in background so whatever application is running at that time that should be closed when a specific hand gesture is shown

Comment: I don't think you mean opencv.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  You surely don't want Python to terminate an application at random.  There has to be an application name.

Comment: i am working on an project which is using opencv. this closes any opened application when an specific hand gesture is given

Comment: actually i want to close any application whenever i run my python code

Comment: Update your question with the above 2 details.

Comment: You could do something like this. i.e., call this function when a gesture is recognized

```python
import os
os.system("taskkill /f /im  Your_Process_Name.exe")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use pyautogui library in python and use this following command
first it will close your your ide but if your code is running in background same as mine it will do the work.

- pyautogui.hotkey('alt','f4')